Plot with Grafana (timeseries panel) only one "field" of a Redis Stream
I've some data in Redis streams
which look like
XRANGE trades-BINANCE-BTC-USDT 1711915630000 1711915637000

1) 1) "1711915630040-0"
   2) 1) "exchange"
      2) "BINANCE"
      3) "symbol"
      4) "BTC-USDT"
      5) "side"
      6) "sell"
      7) "amount"
      8) "0.0003"
      9) "price"
      10) "71029.95"
      11) "id"
      12) "2946737379"

I'd like to plot with Grafana only price in timeseries plot.
I did the following

Query:
Type: Redis
Command: XRANGE
Key: $trades (variable which contains trades-BINANCE-BNB-USDT)
But I'm getting plot of amount, price, id, timestamp, received_timestamp as y-axis and time as x-axis.
Unfortunately I don't know how to only plot price vs time
Any idea?
Do I need custom request with Lua for that purpose?

You can use Transform data feature to Filter by name transformation to keep only the price field.
